# Error to convert objects using @SqlResultMapping and @ConstructorResult to NamedNativeQuery

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, jpa-2.1

guys.

I'm facing this problem for a day and I couldn't find a solution.

I have this scenario:

- Spring Boot
- JPA 2.1
- Hibernate
- I'm using Repository
- The app is a JSON REST service

and this code, my entity Ticket.java:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tickets")
@SqlResultSetMapping(
    name="SummaryReport",
    classes=@ConstructorResult(
            targetClass=ValidatedTicketsVO.class,
            columns={@ColumnResult(name="quantity", 
                                   type=BigInteger.class),
                     @ColumnResult(name="quarter", type=String.class)
            }))
@NamedNativeQuery(
    name="Ticket.findShowSummaryReport",
    query="SELECT COUNT(*) AS quantity, DATE_FORMAT( FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(validation_time) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(validation_time)%(15*60)), \"%d/%m/%Y %H:%i\" ) AS quarter " +
      " FROM tickets " +
      " WHERE show_id = :showId " +
      " GROUP BY quarter " +
      " ORDER BY quarter ")
public class Ticket implements Serializable {
```

I also tried using @EntityResult instead of @ConstructorResult:

```
@SqlResultSetMapping(
    name="SummaryReport",
    entities=@EntityResult(
            entityClass=ValidatedTicketsVO.class,
            fields={@FieldResult(name="quantity", column="quantity"),
                     @FieldResult(name="quarter", column="quarter")
            }))
```

but I got the same error.

and my POJO / VO class that query result has to be mapped to:

```
import java.math.BigInteger;

public class ValidatedTicketsVO {

private BigInteger quantity;
private String quarter;

public ValidatedTicketsVO(BigInteger quantity, String timeQuarter) {
    super();
    this.quantity = quantity;
    this.quarter = timeQuarter;
}

[ getters and setters ]

}
```

PS: the field quantity was initially defined as Integer but as I got a [java.math.BigInteger] exception I changed it to Long and now to BigInteger to see if it solves my problem, but stills the same.

And here is my Repository method:

```
List<ValidatedTicketsVO> findShowSummaryReport(@Param("showId") Long showId);
```

The query is well executed and I can't see any other log rather than the query itself. I get no exception in the log, but I get this response when I try to execute it through Postman:

```
{
"code": 5001,
"description": "Unexpected server error",
"timestamp": 1499782989890,
"errors": 1,
"fieldErrors": [
    {
        "field": "",
        "message": "No converter found capable of converting from type [java.math.BigInteger] to type [br.com.company.validator.model.entity.vo.ValidatedTicketsVO]"
    }
]
```

}

When I debug it on Eclipse the exception occurs when I call this method:

```
List<ValidatedTicketsVO> list = repository.findShowSummaryReport(showId);
```

Can someone help me, please?

Comment: Hibernate/JPA might need a custom type converter for BigInteger. Try using Integer and see if that works. If it does then write a custom type converter for biginteger.

Comment: Thanks @sagneta. I already tried Integer and Long and I get the same error. Do you have any example to create a custom type converter?

Comment: Ya there are a lot of tutorials. https://vladmihalcea.com/2016/09/22/how-to-implement-a-custom-basic-type-using-hibernate-usertype/